# problem with input data in my form submit php

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have a input for input math questions. For math equation I use mathML editor. I copy math html code and write some text with it in my input field. 
just like this:  `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>a</mi><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></msup><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&#xA0;</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>4</mn></msup></math > testing math with text.`

while my previous server it was fine and perfectly inputting. But in this month i change my server and after that it won't working properly.

In my new server it use ea-php7.1 version. Now i only submit one thing at a time just like:   `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>a</mi><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></msup><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&#xA0;</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>4</mn></msup></math >`

If I only submit the math or only text it's work fine but when i input them together just like this:  `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>a</mi><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></msup><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&#xA0;</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>4</mn></msup></math > testing math with text.`

Unfortunately it's won't submit and didn't show me any error. How to fix it?

I've tried to fix it several time in my live server but nothing happen. So i try it in my local server and it's working fine here.

I want to input data like this:  `<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>a</mi><mrow><mn>3</mn><mo>&#xA0;</mo></mrow></msup><mo>&#xA0;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&#xA0;</mo><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>4</mn></msup></math > testing math with text.`

Comment: What is the PHP you are using? What is the status code of the page you load to? Do you have error reporting enabled on the new server, and/or are you checking the logs?

Comment: As @user3783243 sad, turn on `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`